# VBA code Lastrow = cell value

Tags: excel, vba

I usually use the following code to find lastrow.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Sheet2.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This works fine when I don't know what my last row should be. I am trying to use it as this.

```
Dim Lastrow As Integer
Lastrow = Range("U3").Value
```

When I debug the code and hover over

> "range("U3").Value"

it shows

> "range("U3").Value = 558"

but when I hover over

> "Lastrow"

it says

> "Lastrow = Empty"

instead of 558.

The reason I am trying to use this is because the data is being pulled from a master list so I can't use the Rows.Count feature. I instead did a count of a particular value that I am filtering and using that as my last row.

How do I get it to recognize that I want to set the variable "Lastrow" to the value found in U3?

Comment: In one case LastRow is the value of U3 and in the other case it is the integer row number of the last row.  Are you actually trying to find the value a particular cell in the last row?  If so, which cell?

Comment: Things appears to be all right with your code. You must make sure that particular line has already run. I.e.: the yellow marker should be below the line `Lastrow = Range("U3").Value`. Is that the case?
Alternatively, the problem could be that the range you're referencing is in another sheet

Comment: @Jerry Jeremiah No so the one of the integer row number is what I have used in the past. I am trying to tweak it because now I have a cell (U3) that already tells me what the last row is. So I need it to look at value in cell U3 (558) and use that value as the value for "Lastrow". In this case... Lastrow = Range("U3").value would equal lastrow = 558.

Comment: @LucianoFerreira The yellow marker when I debug is on that line. It shows 558 for the right side and 0 for the left side. I tried doing a With statement to specify which sheet to look for and it didn't work.  I've also tried subsituting value with text and it wont work.

Comment: So, move to the next line (F8) and check again. I think it will do. The yellow marker shows the next line to run, so it hasn't yet assigned the value to the variable

Comment: Oh i see what you mean... okay so then my problem lies in this line: Sheet1.Range("B" & Lastrow + 1).EntireRow.End(xlDown).Delete

Comment: This is suppose to grab the row below the last row and everything below it and delete it all.

Comment: @LucianoFerreira Do you know why everything will work except "Sheet1.Range("B" & Lastrow + 1).EntireRow.End(xlDown).Delete"

Comment: Well, I think the main part of the question (the debug thing) is settled. If other parts of the code are returning errors it is the case of making a new question. Either way, about that last thing, try `Sheets(1).` instead of `Sheet1.`

Answer (score 0):

If I insert "558" in cell A3 (not U3) and run this code it produces "558" in the immediate window:

```
Sub test()

    Dim Lastrow As Integer
    Dim sheet1 As Worksheet

    Set sheet1 = ActiveSheet
    Lastrow = sheet1.Range("A3").Value2
    Debug.Print Lastrow

End Sub
```

Sure, when you step through it with the debugger and hover over the line where `Lastrow` is being set, it says "Lastrow = 0", but that's just because the variable has not been set yet. Clearly, it is indeed being set correctly as the `Debug.Print` statement in the next line produces the expected output.